# Get specific attribute data from Json

Tags: python, json, django

I'm implemented a code to return Json value like this

```
{ "key1":"1", "key2":"2", ......}
```

But I want to get only value of key1. so I first defined info to get Json.

```
info = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

And use `info.text['key1']` to get value of key1. but i got error. could anyone suggest any solution?

Comment: `info.json().get('key1')` (always use `get` on dictionaries!)

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
info = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
jsonObject = json.loads(info)
key1= jsonObject['key1']
```

or

```
jsonObject = info.json()
key1= jsonObject['key1']
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON is a format, but the data are included as text. Inside the `info.text` you have a string. 
If you want to access the json data you can do `info.json()['key1']`. This will work only if the response content type is defined as JSON, to check that do 
info.headers['content-type'] should be `application/json; charset=utf8`

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/

Otherwise you will have to manually load the text to json, with `json` library for example

```
import json
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
data = json.loads(response.text)
```